# Setting dialog property value in SetValidate call does not work

Tags: botframework

Given the following formflow setup...

```
return builder
    .Field(new FieldReflector<CarValuationDialog>(nameof(Mileage))
        .SetValidate(async (state, value) =>
            {
                var result = new ValidateResult { IsValid = true };

                if (int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out int mileage))
                {
                    state.Mileage = mileage;
                    result.IsValid = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    result.Feedback = "That isn't valid number. Can you enter it again please?";
                    result.IsValid = false;
                }

                return result;
            }))

    .Field(new FieldReflector<CarValuationDialog>(nameof(HappyWithAnswersBuying))
        .SetActive(carValuationDialog => carValuationDialog.ValuationOption == ValuationOptions.LookingToOwn)
        .SetPrompt(CreateHappyWithAnswersBuyingPrompt())
        .SetDefine(HappyWithAnswersDefinitionMethod))
    .OnCompletion(GetValuationAndDisplaySummaryToUser)
    .Build();
```

I want to try out custom validation on the mileage answer given by the user. The code in `SetValidate` executes, and given a valid integer, that number is assigned to `state.Mileage`.

However, when the prompt asking the user if they are happy with the answers is shown, the mileage is still set to 0..

[image]

Here is the code for the prompt..

```
private static PromptAttribute CreateHappyWithAnswersBuyingPrompt()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100);

    sb.Append("Are you happy with your answers? <br /><br />");
    sb.Append("{&RegistrationNumber}: {RegistrationNumber} <br />");
    sb.Append("{&Mileage}: {Mileage:N0} miles {||}");

    return new PromptAttribute(sb.ToString())
    {
        ChoiceStyle = ChoiceStyleOptions.Buttons,
        FieldCase = CaseNormalization.InitialUpper
    };
}
```

Before I added the `SetValidate` code, the mileage was shown perfectly fine in the prompt. But since I'm now manually setting `state.Mileage`, it's not being persisted across for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Man, I seriously need to "check the plug" on my code...

Basically I had not set the `Value` property of the `ValidateResult` instance...

```
.SetValidate(async (state, value) =>
{
    var result = new ValidateResult { IsValid = true, Value = value };

    ....
}
```

After doing that, the mileage value now appears in the prompt...

[image]